# Checkbox showing checked after clicking on another checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

There is a tree structure with checkbox. Already discussed [Previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144488/checkboxes-showing-checked-by-default)

I'm facing problem that, when i click on an item, it checked but not showing checked in console.
When i click on another item, the first item shows in the check-list but not currently clicked item. This item will be shown there after i click on another item.

So, it's working but not at the time when i'm clicking on the item, but after clicking another item.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggle = function() {
    //var id = $(this).parent().find('input:first')[0].id;
    //$("#"+id).find("input").prop('checked', 'checked');
    //$(this).find("input").prop('checked', true);
    //console.log($(this).parent().find('input:first')[0].id);
    if (!$(this).closest("li").find("ul:first").is(":visible") && $(this).closest("li").is(":visible")) {
      //console.log("checked");
      $(this).parent('li:has(>ul)').find("span:first").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign");
    } else {
      //console.log("unchecked");
      $(this).parent('li:has(>ul)').find("span:first").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign");
    }
    $(this).parent().children().toggle();
    $(this).toggle();
    console.log($('input[name="level1"]:checked'));
    console.log($('input[name="level2"]:checked'));
    console.log($('input[name="level3"]:checked'));
  };
  $(".Collapsable").click(toggle);
  $(".Collapsable").each(toggle);
  $('.tree li:not(:has(>ul))').find("span:first").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark");
});
```

```css
ul.tree,
ul.tree ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.tree ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

ul.tree li {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

ul.tree li:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}

ul.tree li:before {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.3em;
  height: 1em;
  width: 12px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  left: -7px;
}

ul.tree li:last-child:before {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px\9;
  margin-left: -20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: initial;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="tree">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="level1" id="Parent_1">
        <label class="Collapsable" for="Parent_1">
          <span></span> Parent_1
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="level2" id="Child_1_1">
            <label class="Collapsable" for="Child_1_1">
              <span></span> Child_1_1
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="level2" id="Child_1_2">
            <label class="Collapsable" for="Child_1_2">
              <span></span> Child_1_2
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="level3" id="Grand_Child_1_2_1">
                <label class="Collapsable" for="Grand_Child_1_2_1">
                  <span></span> Grand_Child_1_2_2
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="level3" id="Grand_Child_1_2_2">
                <label class="Collapsable" for="Grand_Child_1_2_2">
                  <span></span> Grand_Child_1_2_2
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="level1" id="Parent_2">
        <label class="Collapsable" for="Parent_2">
          <span></span> Parent_2
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="level2" id="Child_2_1">
            <label class="Collapsable" for="Child_2_1">
              <span></span> Child_2_1
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="level2" id="Child_2_2">
            <label class="Collapsable" for="Child_2_2">
              <span></span> Child_2_2
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="level3" id="Grand_Child_2_2_1">
                <label class="Collapsable" for="Grand_Child_2_2_1">
                  <span></span> Grand_Child_2_2_2
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="level3" id="Grand_Child_2_2_2">
                <label class="Collapsable" for="Grand_Child_2_2_2">
                  <span></span> Grand_Child_2_2_2
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="level1" id="Parent_3">
        <label class="Collapsable" for="Parent_3">
          <span></span> Parent_3
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="level2" id="Child_3_1">
            <label class="Collapsable" for="Child_3_1">
              <span></span> Child_3_1
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="level3" id="Grand_Child_3_1_1">
                <label class="Collapsable" for="Grand_Child_3_1_1">
                  <span></span> Grand_Child_3_1_1
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="level3" id="Grand_Child_3_1_2">
                <label class="Collapsable" for="Grand_Child_3_1_2">
                  <span></span> Grand_Child_3_1_2
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="level2" id="Child_3_1">
            <label class="Collapsable" for="Child_3_1">
              <span></span> Child_3_1
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is wrong with the checkbox..? Am i missing something?

Code is taking too long while running on snippet, for ref [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/5vnuhhp8/)

Comment: When I click on an item, it turns red. When I click it again, it goes back to black. What's supposed to happen instead?

Comment: Check checkboxes are hidden, how can you tell if it's checked or not?

Comment: First of all change `var` name `toggle` to something else, JS have some [Reserved Words](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: @Barmar i commented the console.log, once you open the jsfiddle then you find that after clicking on the item, it turns to red and checked but in console, it is not showing checked. Got my point?
Even if you want to check whether checkboxes are checked or not, see the log.

Comment: @Barmar and if it was working fine, then why would i put this as a question here..
I suggest that, Go through the question properly before down-vote it.

Comment: You're logging the checkboxes in the click handler for the `<label>`. The related checkbox doesn't get checked until after that handler returns.

Comment: This allows you to call `event.preventDefault()` in the handler, then the checkbox won't be checked.

Comment: You wouldn't be the first person to post a question where we couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed, so where should i put the code for checking which items are checked or not, after handler returns?
But still, i don't think so that there is anything wrong with the question, so why down-voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, why are you asking me?

Comment: Put the click handler on the checkbox instead of the label.

Comment: @Barmar let me try then, thanks for your response.
and i thought, you commented first so probably you down-voted..:/

Comment: Common mistake. I tried changing your fiddle to use `$(":checkbox").click(toggle)` but then clicking on something made it disappear. I don't understand your code well enough to know why.

Comment: @Barmar That's why we are here on EARTH...:)
Actually, "<input type="checkbox" name="level1" id="Parent_1"><label class="Collapsable" for="Parent_1">" works fine everywhere, but here it is not working, maybe because of the nested <ul><li>?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163049/discussion-between-rohit-bisht-and-barmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on a label, the click on the associated checkbox doesn't occur until after the label's click handler returns. So while the label's handler is running, the checkbox isn't checked yet.

You should put the click handler on the checkboxes instead of the labels. But then this code doesn't work right:

```
$(this).parent().children().toggle();
$(this).toggle();
```

because `$(this)` isn't the label, it's the checkbox. As a result, the label disappears when you click on it. Change that code to:

```
$(this).parent().children().toggle();
if ($(this).is(":checkbox")){
    $(`label[for=${this.id}]`).toggle();
} else {
    $(this).toggle();
}
```

So when you call `toggle()` from the checkbox click handler, it toggles the label for this checkbox.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5vnuhhp8/7/) - only the first two checkboxes have the `Collapsable` class that's used in the event binding, so clicking on the rest doesn't do anything.

Comment: Nice trick. but demo fiddle not working properly. i can't able to expand the other tree elements.

Comment: I only added `class="Collapsable1"` to the first two checkboxes in the fiddle.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai for you, i did... https://jsfiddle.net/rbrohitbisht/5vnuhhp8/8/